# Make with multiple compilers

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang, libstdc++, libc++

When using C++14/C++11 features and STL includes, GCC and clang have different behaviors.  Libc++ has a tendency to include things implicitly, while libstdc++ seems to have a tendency to require explicit includes.  GCC -Wpedantic seems to be a little more pedantic than clang -Wpedantic.

What I want is to have a makefile that attempts to build with both of these compilers, in order to catch errors.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, `make`'s job is only to test with *one* particular set of options. Testing multiple configurations is the job of some higher-level script.

First, set up your project so that it can do out-of-tree builds. Usually a script named `configure` is used to do this.

Then, for each configuration, create an out-of-tree build:

```
pushd; mkdir build-gcc-libstdc++ && cd build-gcc-libstdc++ && ../configure CXX='g++'; popd
pushd; mkdir build-gcc-libc++ && cd build-gcc-libc++ && ../configure CXX='g++-libc++'; popd
pushd; mkdir build-clang-libstdc++ && cd build-clang-libstdc++ && ../configure CXX='clang++'; popd
pushd; mkdir build-clang-libc++ && cd build-clang-libc++ && ../configure CXX='clang++-libc++'; popd
```

(You may also want to do this for multiple gcc versions, since the headers vary a lot between them too).

To run them all, do:

```
make -C build-gcc-libstdc++ [targets ...] &&
make -C build-gcc-libc++ [targets ...] &&
make -C build-clang-libstdc++ [targets ...] &&
make -C build-clang-libc++ [targets ...]
```

but usually I just build with the default configuration and let travis catch errors from other configurations. Note that I don't use libc++: https://github.com/themanaworld/tmwa/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: What's stopping you from making a target that has all of these options in your makefile?

Comment: @CarlNorum Nothing (just remember to use `${MAKE}` instead of `make`), but it's of quite limited usefulness in most workflows. Quick turnaround is most important for WIP builds, and at commit time it doesn't make much difference if you type `make poly` vs `./make-poly.sh`